# 'No provider' error (even though I've added a provider)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to call a service from a particular class, but for some reason it can't be called, even though I am able to use it in other classes. I'm using `@Input`. I don't know if this is causing the problem.

Code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Category } from './../Category';
import { CertService } from './../../shared/Service/cert.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cert-item',
  templateUrl: './cert-item.component.html'
})
export class CertItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() category: Category;
  @Input() categoryId: number;
  constructor(
    private certService: CertService //Console error "No provider for CertService!"
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.certService.getCategories());
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header.component';
import { DropdownDirective } from './dropdown.directive';
import { CertsComponent } from './certs/certs.component';
import { CertItemComponent } from './certs/cert-category/cert-item.component';

import { CertService } from './shared/service/cert.service';
import { HttpService } from './shared/Service/http.service';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    DropdownDirective,
    CertsComponent,
    CertItemComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    CertService, 
    HttpService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Service class I'm trying to call (sample):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CertService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getCategories() {
    return this.http.get('api/categories')
   .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

I also can't get the current route, using:

```
this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params) => {...

...});
```

Again, the code above works fine in other classes but not in this class.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Is that service in the relevant module-level `providers` array?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - The service is in the relevant `providers: []` in the app.module.ts file.  It is being used by other classes but it cannot be used in this class.  I assume everything else (apart from this class) works because I have used them before without any problems.  Also, I use Visual Studio Code,  it gives me no errors and I can import the Service automatically.  The error only occurs when I run it in the browser

Comment: is the service provided in the same module that declares your component?

Comment: Post the content of the app.module where you inject the service. Do you have the service imported from a bundle index.ts file ? there are some issues with that.

Comment: @tibbus, @EvansM. - I've added the Service and AppModule code.  My index.ts file only contains `export * from './app.component';` and `export * from './app.module';`.

Comment: This will happen if you've provided something wrong as a provider. And it is unlikely that there may be another reason for this. In one place it is `...shared/service/cert.service`, and in another it is `...shared/Service/cert.service`. I'm not sure what happens with it during build process, but this is very bad. Case matters. As a no-brainer debugging effort, you can expose `CertService` from both files as `window.CertService1` and `window.CertService2` and compare in console if both are defined and equal.

Comment: Sure, I will. I guess this question may be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen if something wrong was provided as a provider. And it is unlikely that there may be another reason for this.

In one place it is `...shared/service/cert.service`, and in another it is `...shared/Service/cert.service`. Case matters. It depends on the environment what happens with these modules during build process, but this can cause errors, e.g. they may become duplicated and refer to different objects.

To quickly debug this, `CertService` can be exposed from both files as `window.CertService1` and `window.CertService2` and compared in console if both are defined and equal.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using **symbolic links** with 'yarn link ' and didn't have the build option '**preserveSymlinks**' set to **true** in angular.json file.

Details:

If you're using symbolic links, first make a sanity-check: unlink them, rebuild and see if the problem persists. If it does not, it means there's a problem with the angular symlink build.

In that case, check your angular.json file and make sure you have the option 'preserveSymlinks' set to true:

```
"projects": {
"my-project": {
  "projectType": "application",
  [...]
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same error message ("*No provider for SomeService*") can be triggered by having another service with the same name in your app. So it would look like you correctly included *SomeService #1* in your module, added to the providers section, but it would still throw you the error. It puzzled me until I realized that there's *SomeService #2* being imported in one of my components.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I imported the service as

```
import {MyService} from '../services/my.service'
```

in one place, and

```
import {MyService} from '../services/index'
```

in the other place, while index.ts contains all export statements for services in the same folder.

After I unified to the 2nd form of importing, the problem had gone.