# Angular2 : EXCEPTION: No provider for Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics

Tags: javascript, angular, angulartics, angulartics2

I am trying to use [`angulartics2`](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2) with my application.

I have configured correctly as it mentioned in the document.

**Note:**  There is no place it is mentioned to add the provider as a dependency..

When i try to run the application, it shows the error as below.

> EXCEPTION: No provider for Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics! Error: DI
>   Error
>       at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (zone.js:811)
>       at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (core.umd.js:1186)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (core.umd.js:1371)
>       at new NoProviderError (core.umd.js:1411)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.umd.js:3394)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (core.umd.js:3433)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (core.umd.js:3380)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (core.umd.js:3140)
>       at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.umd.js:8996)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (core.umd.js:12465)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (core.umd.js:12845)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal
>   (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:15)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (core.umd.js:12421)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (core.umd.js:12829)
>       at ComponentFactory.create (core.umd.js:7766)   [1](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2): https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics } from 'angulartics2';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: `./app.component.html`,
  styleUrls: ['/app.componenet.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'Angular2 google analytics';
constructor(angulartics2GoogleAnalytics: Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics) {}
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { Angulartics2Module, Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics } from 'angulartics2';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ HttpModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule, Angulartics2Module.forRoot([ Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics ])],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - No Provider error (even though I've added a provider)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796587/angular-2-no-provider-error-even-though-ive-added-a-provider)

Comment: Yes, it should be done like you've done. This may happen if the modules became duplicated, and `Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics` refers to different classes in different modules. You have `App.component.ts` but import `./app.component`, this may indicate that you were careless with case, and it would lead to module duplication. I would suggest to check if `Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics` is really the same class in all modules, as it were suggested in the answer in dupe question.

Comment: @estus No it dint work ! i have tried for 2 hours

Comment: To make sure, by 'it'` you mean that you tried to expose `Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics` as `window` property in both classes, and it was `===` equal when you compared it? If you can't provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can replicate the issue, I don't think that anything can be suggested as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem should reside in your constructor:

```
constructor(angulartics2GoogleAnalytics: Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics) {}
```

you should add e.g `public` in front of your provider:

```
constructor(public angulartics2GoogleAnalytics: Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics) {}
```

Comment: Strangely enough, making this public in the injector is also required.  I had this as private, and flipping it to public fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

use `providers` to initiate your providers in component.

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'yourselector',
    styleUrls: [''],
    templateUrl: '',
    providers: [Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics]
})
```

Try this.

Comment: The providers block is a required piece!