# How to not import useless imports in angular component tests, when testing a component with a dependency?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code. It keeps telling me that there is no provider for AlertService. I have provided the AlertServiceSpy class, but it still says that there is no provider for AlertService. As soon as I add CoreModule and RouterTestingModule to the imports it starts working.

This must be because the AlertService has a dependency on them, however this is completely unimportant in this test. I just want to test the AlertComponent and don't care about the dependencies of the AlertService, hence I've mocked it. Why would I need to import AlertService's dependencies into this test? Please help!

```
describe('AlertComponent', () => {

  let comp: AlertComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AlertComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;
  let alertService: any;

  class AlertServiceSpy {

    getMessage = jasmine.createSpy('getMessage').and.callFake(
        () => Observable
            .create((observer) => {
                return 'message';
            })
    );

  }


  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
      ],
      declarations: [        
        AlertComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AlertService, useClass: AlertServiceSpy }
      ]

    }).overrideComponent(AlertComponent, {

      set: {
        providers: [
          { provide: AlertService, useClass: AlertServiceSpy }
        ]
      }

    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AlertComponent);
    }));
  });

  // TESTS
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));

});
```

Alert component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertService } from '../Alert/alert.service';

@Component({
    moduleId:       module.id,
    selector:       'app-alert-system',
    templateUrl:    'alert.component.html',
})

export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {

    public message: any;

    constructor( private alertService: AlertService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.alertService.getMessage().subscribe(
            message => { 
                this.message = message; 
            });
    }
}
```

Alert service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { HttpAlertGenerator } from './http-alert-generator'

/*
    Service used for handling alerts.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {

    private _subject = new Subject<any>();
    private _keepAfterNavigationChange = false;
    private _httpAlertGenerator = new HttpAlertGenerator();

    constructor(private router: Router) {

        router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                if (this._keepAfterNavigationChange) {
                    this._keepAfterNavigationChange = false;
                } else {
                    this._subject.next();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    // public
    public httpAlert(errCode: number, 
                     additionalInfo: string,
                     keepAfterNavigationChange = true, 
                     displayDurationInMillis?: number) {

        const message = additionalInfo + ' ' + this._httpAlertGenerator.codeToMessage(errCode);

        if (errCode >= 300) {
            this.error(message, keepAfterNavigationChange);
        } else {
            this.success(message, keepAfterNavigationChange);
        }
    }

    public success(message: string, keepAfterNavigationChange = true, timeLimit = 5000) {
        this._keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
        this._subject.next({type: 'success', text: message});
        this.prepareNext(timeLimit);
    }

    public error(message: string, keepAfterNavigationChange = true) {
        this._keepAfterNavigationChange = keepAfterNavigationChange;
        this._subject.next({type: 'error', text: message});
    }

    // FOR ALERT COMPONENT
    public getMessage(): Observable<any> {
            return this._subject.asObservable();
    }

    private prepareNext(timelimit = 5000) {
        const nextSubj = this._subject;
        setTimeout(function(){
            nextSubj.next();
        }, timelimit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you declared AlertService as a provider in app.module.ts? also in   let alertService: any; could be   let alertService: AlertService;

Comment: I changed it into alertService: AlertService. I provide it in the Core module, which I also import into app.module

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the problem, it was basically unrelated to the test itself, and it's a bit weird.

The problem was that somewhere down the line, I changed my folder names from uppercase to lowercase. Git didn't recognize this change and kept the old folder names.

In my AlertComponent I imported the service from ../Alert/alert.service, while I was still in the same folder. I changed this to ./alert.service and the thing magically started working. It seems that I'll have to take more care in the naming of my folders.

I got the tips from the following article:

[Angular 2 - No Provider error (even though I've added a provider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796587/angular-2-no-provider-error-even-though-ive-added-a-provider)